# Apache httpd.conf change without restart the server

Tags: apache

According to my client requirement every time a user register to software we need to provide a separate URL. For that we are using apache and registering the new url in apache httpd.conf. Now the issue is after every new url entry we need to restart the apache server to reflect the changes. But this approach is bad because restarting the apache server also effecting the existing client. So, I would like to reflect the changes without restarting.

**So, an any one help me to do that with apache.
I am also open for other tools if that can solve my issue.**

Comment: If you restart the apache `graceful`, it should not have an effect on the existing clients.

Answer (score 1):

Apache can't update it's configuration without restart (graceful or clean).

It's a bad idea to store generated URLs in Apache config.

Much better is to use [rewrite maps](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) or store URLs in database and rewrite them with [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/)

Comment: I found a option called "reload". Also through "graceful" we can achieve the same without effecting existing customer. right?

Also can you elaborate bit more about the solution you have given?

Comment: "reload" do the same as "graceful", it's just an alias. Update your question with a detailed description of your task if you want to get a detailed solution :)